# How to set npm registry only for the specific project

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm using a private npm registry for one of my npm packages and I also have a couple of other packages referenced from the default npm registry. What I'm doing at the moment is:

```
npm config set registry https://private.registry.endpoint
```

However, this changes the registry globally. I can manually create a `.npmrc` at the root of my project and set the registry manually inside. This does not replace my global registry and uses the private registry only for the specific project. However, I want to do this with a command, instead of having to manually create the `.npmrc` and set the registry.

In case you're wondering why I need this, I know how to do it myself, however I have to guide other users how to do it, and it would be simpler to just provide a command for them. I need to know if there is a way to do something of the sort:

```
npm config --local set registry https://private.registry.endpoint
```

Comment: what private registry are you using? npm for business? artifactory?

Comment: It's this one https://packages.infragistics.com/npm/js-licensed

Comment: ehm... does not look like an npm provider... However, are the [scoped packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope) supported?

Comment: It's a proget server so scoped packages seem to be supported. I figured scoping the package that this may be the best option for now.

Comment: Yes I think so. They are really good in separating repos

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We solved this problem by scoping our private packages, which allows us to add the private registry only for the specific `@scope` instead of changing the entire default registry to download the private packages.

E.g.

If we have a package named `package-name`, in our private registry we publish it as `@company/package-name` and then set the private registry scope to be `@company`.

`npm config set @company:registry https://private.registry.endpoint`

Comment: Could you please explain this a little bit more to us? I don't understand it.

Comment: Thanks! I presume that if the private package was not published under a namespace, this can't be used. In the end I used .npmrc to set the registry just for the project. But still, npm search for every new package installed first in that private repository (under VPN, so when not connected, it fails). At least, this settings is not global now.

Comment: @actimel Yes, this is correct. If you don't scope the registry, then your public package requests will also hit the same private registry and would fail.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the issue. Solved it by putting a `.npmrc` file in the project root and assign the desired registry.

Comment: i did this but it still ended up calling my private repository, even tho "npm config get registry" returned the default npm repo i wanted.

Comment: @JesseBoyd You can try modifying your global .npmrc file at the root of your user directory.

Answer (score 5):

What you seek exists with the `--location project` option. See below:

```
npm config --location project set registry https://private.registry.endpoint
```

Comment: This is actually a very good concise answer. I would only add that you need to run this command from the root of the project - where package.json is located - to avoid possible conflicts.

Comment: this is the only one that worked for me.  scopes won't work for a corporate private repo when you need another project with the public npm repo